# Windows share smb connection hangs on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows, samba, ubuntu-20.04, nas, network-share

I have a VPN restricted share network on a server (Win 10), and after I connect to VPN and try to connect to that shared network on my Ubuntu 20.04 client (Ubuntu Desktop) via GUI. By GUI, I mean specifically applying these steps:

1. Open "Files" browser.
2. Select "+ Other Locations" on the left side-bar menu.
3. Type your server to connect on "Connect to server", mine was something like `smb://myServer/shared/` and click "Connect".
4. When a login prompt appears, write down your credentials (or login anonymously).
5. You should have access to that shared network now.

When I did those steps above before upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, when I was using Ubuntu 18.04, I was able to successfully access to the shared network.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, however, on the step 4 (after I enter my credentials and try to connect) the connection just hangs, and the shared network is not mounted.

After researching the problem a bit, the potential solutions I found did not work, most of which
suggests to add the following to `smb.conf` to be able to access to SMB1 type of network.

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
```

**Reference**

- [Can't acces NAS anymore after upgrading to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229929/cant-acces-nas-anymore-after-upgrading-to-20-04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, what I tried aside is to mount the shared folder manually with the following command

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/my_share
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=name,password=pw //server/shared /mnt/my_share/
```

which strangely worked.

I do not have a clue why "Files" did not work and manually doing it worked. I cannot say the former failed completely because after entering credentials on login prompt there was no error, but just hangs.